# how can i change drawer items on user state flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, refresh, drawer

how can i change the drawer items on flutter depending on the user state
the drawer has 2 items sign in and sign out and when i press sign out the user signed out but the drawer dose not change the log out button still visible and i should reload the page so its disappear and the sign in button appears

```
if (_auth.currentUser == null)
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Sign In'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              else
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('My Cars'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyCars()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Sign Out'),
                      onTap: () {
                        signOut();
                        
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

also the sign in has navigation function that navigate to the screen that has the drawer but when this happen the the drawer is still show the sign in button and i should navigate again to change it

Answer (score 1):

wrap listile into the `visibility` widget,

```
Visibility (
    visible: _visible
    child: ListTile(...)
);
```

declare a boolean variable `_visible` and set it's value. you can check all condition and make it true false in `setState` to hide and show `ListTile`.

```
setState(() {
    _visible = false;
});

setState(() {
    _visible = true;
});
```

Comment: it works for me with sign up list title but idk know how to apply this change on the sign in as its in another screen do you have any idea on how to do this?